# popen3 and return code

Tags: python

I want to get stdout and stderr of a command along with the return code. 
Can someone point me to a python function that already accomplishes this?

I modified a function that I found on this site as follows -- but I am not able to grab the return code of the command. In this snippet, sts always seems to be 0.

```
def Getstatusoutput(cmd):
    """Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a shell."""

    import sys
    mswindows = (sys.platform == "win32")

    import os
    if not mswindows:
        cmd = '{ ' + cmd + '; }'

    fi,fo,fe=os.popen3(cmd)
    textOut = fo.read()
    textErr = fe.read()
    sts = fo.close()
    if sts is None: sts = 0
    if textOut[-1:] == '\n': textOut = textOut[:-1]
    return sts, textOut, textErr
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.  [This section](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3) shows how to replace `os.popen3` calls.